# Agrupar información en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT * FROM INFO
```

y el resulta es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que la información de la fila de Foraneas se sume el total_1, total_2 porcentaje, incentivo_1 e incentivo_2, seria igual para Mazatlan y Morelos.

El resultado seria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es un agrupamiento por la columna "nombre", mientras utilizas el metodo de suma en las demás columnas:

```
SELECT nombre, SUM(total_1), SUM(total_2), SUM(porcentaje), SUM(incentivo_1), SUM(incentivo_2)
FROM INFO
GROUP BY nombre
```

Saludos.